# Redis return null value to id column

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, redis, spring-data-redis, spark-redis

I'm write a dataframe to redis and read the data with spring boot application. The information retry successfull, but the id column return null like that:

{
"nu_document": null,
"qt_negative": "1000000000"
}

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. you might be missing

```
.option("key.column", "nu_document")
```

from your read method. Check out the link https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/blob/master/doc/dataframe.md.

Comment: My write code ==> df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis").option("table", "summary").option("key.column", "nu_document").mode(SaveMode.Append).save()

Comment: yeah that is right. but you need to mention the key column in the read method too if that is missing.

Comment: but, I'm not read with spark, I'm reading with spring boot, i said above in the question.

Comment: oh sorry. my bad. i was working with Spark. So was thinking on the same track.

Comment: my repository ==> personRepository.findById(id). The return is {"nu_document": null, "qt_negative": "1000000000"}. so nu_documento is null